# Javascript: How to remove the eventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the event listener below using Javascript?

```
    var commentArea=$(this).parent().find('.comment_input_content')[0];

    commentEditDropbox = commentArea;
    commentEditDropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
    commentEditDropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
    commentEditDropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
    function dragenter(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      // $("#topic_content_input").css("cursor:copy");        
    }
    function dragover(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      // $("#topic_content_input").css("cursor:copy");
    }
    function drop(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      // $("#topic_content_input").css("cursor:copy");
      var dt = e.dataTransfer;
      var files = dt.files;
      var attr = $(this).attr('contenteditable');
      // if contenteditable is true
      if(attr){
      commentEditHandleFileSelect(files);
      alert("drop");
        }
    }
```

I tired code below simply by replacing addEventListener to removeEventlistener, but not working :(

```
var commentArea=$(this).parent().find('.comment_input_content')[0];

commentEditDropbox = commentArea;
commentEditDropbox.removeEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
commentEditDropbox.removeEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
commentEditDropbox.removeEventListener("drop", drop, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using JQuery to select the element you want so you'll get a jQuery selector object.

I would suggest changing addEventListener to on and removeEventListener to off.

```
commentEditDropbox.on("dragenter", dragenter);
commentEditDropbox.on("dragover", dragover);
commentEditDropbox.on("drop", drop);

commentEditDropbox.off("dragenter", dragenter);
commentEditDropbox.off("dragover", dragover);
commentEditDropbox.off("drop", drop);
```

Comment: it prints error when I change it :SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal "dragover"

Comment: Do you have time to look at the whole script? It is a drag and drop image handle function. The problem with addEventListener is that it sometimes add the same listener to same object more than one time, so I have to remove it. JQuery on and off method could help me solving the problem fundamentally, but I have problem switch it to JQuery, it prints error, could you help?

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to include more code?